# Parse Cloud Code afterSave not working

Tags: xcode, push-notification, parse-platform

Hey I'm using Parse as my backend and I love it but I have a problem with the afterSave hook.

Here is the Code I'm using:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave ("JGZwoelf",function (request) {

                       Parse.Push.send({
                                       //Selecting the Channel
                                       channels: [ request.object.get('JGZwoelfPush') ],

                                            data: {
                                            //Selecting the Key inside the Class
                                            alert: request.object.get('AusfallInfo')

                                            }
                                       }, {
                                            success: function () {
                                            //Push was send successfully
                                            },

                                            error: function (error) {
                                            //Handle error
                                            throw "Got an error" + error.code + " : " + error.message;
                                            }


                                       });
                       });
```

Every time the logs console is telling me: Result:

> Uncaught Got an error112 : Missing channel name.

I just don't understand what is wrong! It must be in that JavaScript code. If I enter the push notification manually everything works fine :/

Edit:
The part Parse.Push.send should look like this:

```
Parse.Push.send ({
        //Selecting the already existing Push Channel
        channels: ["JGAchtPush"], //This has to be the name of your push channel!!
        data: {
            //Selecting the Key inside the Class
            alert: request.object.get ("AusfallInfo")
        }
    }, {
        success: function () {
            //Push was sent successfully
            //nothing was loged
        },
        error: function (error) {
            throw "Got and error" + error.code + " : " + error.message;
        }
    });
```

The channel name needs to be something like ["exampleChannel"].

Thanks in advance for any given help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to afterSave should be a class name, not an objectId.

Answer (score 1):

following is for new folks (like me), it is the exact same code in original question, plus a few more comments, plus the correction from accepted answer.  purpose is to show example of what few pieces of code need changing for this to work in your parse cloud code. thank you Constantin Jacob and bklimt.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave ("UserVideoMessage",function (request) { // name of my parse class is "UserVideoMessage"

    Parse.Push.send ({
        //Selecting the already existing Push Channel
        channels: ["admin"], //This has to be the name of your push channel!!
        data: {
            //Selecting the Key inside the Class, this will be the content of the push notification
            alert: request.object.get ("from")
        }
    }, {
        success: function () {
            //Push was sent successfully
            //nothing was loged
        },
        error: function (error) {
            throw "Got and error" + error.code + " : " + error.message;
        }
    });

});
```